# how to resize and customize AlertView with image and button

Tags: ios, image, button, alertview

I first use " `[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:` " to resize and customize `AlertView` with image but failed.

Then I use following codes, all works fine ( alertView resized and have a image with it), But just can't have a button to dismiss the alertView. Stuck here for half day. Please help, thanks!

```
UIAlertView* find = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,420)];
    [find setDelegate:self];
    [find setTitle:@"Sample Alert"];
    [find setNeedsLayout];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 80, 80)];

NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"111.png"]];
UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[imageView setImage:bkgImg];
[bkgImg release];
[path release];

 [find addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];

[find show];
find.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,200);

[find release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIAlertView` was not made to be initialized in such a manner. Usually you initialize a `UIAlertView` using `initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:` .

You can try using `[find addButtonWithTitle:@"button 1"];` . You will also need to implement the [UIAlertView Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAlertViewDelegate) to interact with the button.

If that does not work, i recommend implementing your own custom view if you are looking for a heavily modified look.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks KDaker so much! Only '[find addButtonWithTitle:@"button 1"];' is enough and works. It can dismiss AlertView. No need to implement the UIAlertView Delegate to interact with the button any more.

Comment: Thanks KDaker so much! Only '[find addButtonWithTitle:@"button 1"];' is enough and works. It can dismiss AlertView. No need to implement the UIAlertView Delegate to interact with the button any more. But there are 2 things unsatisfactory, one is that, the button is not align with the right and left edge of the alertview. The button's right edge is out of the right edge of the alert view. Although I resize and enlarge the alertView, the button is still out of the alertview. Is there a way to resize the button? Another thing unsatisfactory is that the alertView shakes once after it pops up.

Comment: UIAlertView does not give you control over it's button's frames. And i honestly would not recommend customizing UIAlertView too much because you could risk rejection from apple if you're submitting to the app store. Can you post a screenshot of what you have and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: So coincident that I also realized that I should have post a screenshot. Is it already too much that being risk of rejection by Apple so far ? Sorry, I tried to post a screenshot but failed. Please check the screenshot here, thanks! https://devforums.apple.com/message/719287

Comment: well if you add a text message it would push the button down. But still i see what you are trying to achieve... Try initializing the alertView with `initWithTitle` the normal way and then just add your image as a subView : `[find addSubview:myImageView]`, you might need to place arbitrary text in the message just to resize the alertView.

Comment: This is great! "add a text message" to resize the alert view is really a good method, also avoid the risk of rejection. I had used 'initWithTitle' before but just don't know this wise method, so have to go a long way as above posts. Although it still pop up not graceful with a shake, works anyway! Thanks KDaker again!

Comment: BTW I had wanted to use other method to achieve the effect but failed. So select AlerView. There are other posts suggest to use ' - (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    alertView.frame = CGRectMake(alertView.frame.origin.x, alertView.frame.origin.y-80,alertView.frame.size.width , alertView.frame.size.height+130);
}' , but my program just does not go into willPresentAlertView, even I set a point there. Don't know why.

Comment: were you setting the delegate to the alertView?